# How to set up EventHandler in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

Given the following code snippet:

```
public event EventHandler<PointerEventHandler> onDrawBtnExited;
private void drawBtn_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    onDrawBtnExited(this, e);
}
```

VisualStudio says, that onDrawBtnExited can't take the argument e of type PointerRoutedEventArgs. How can I now pass the PointerRoutedEventArgs?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. What are you *really* trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PointerRoutedEventArgs should be the generic parameter.

```
public event EventHandler<PointerRoutedEventArgs> onDrawBtnExited;
```

You may have created your own delegate somewhere called PointerEventHandler.
In that case, use it in place of the templated EventHandler like so:

```
public event PointerEventHandler onDrawBtnExited;
```